# PDF form validations not working

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, forms, foxit-reader

I have created a PDF form with using Adobe Acrobat and added javascript  validations on text-boxes like email and telephone numbers.

When I fill them with using adobe reader they will validate entries correctly, but if I use another reader like Foxit reader it won't validate my fields.

Comment: Have you ensured that Foxit supports JS form validation just like Adobe reader does?

Comment: @Karan No I didn't, Thought all readers are on universal convention. Thanks, will check

Comment: PDF is a convoluted spec and no, not all readers will support all aspects of it equally well.

Comment: Foxit is too dumb; it is said to be fast displaying PDFs, but their maker decided to not implement JavaScript (as far as I remember). Best practice is to prepare the form for dumb viewers, and activate the smart part in a document-level script, which gets properly interpreted when the viewer understands JavaScript, but remains otherwise ignored.